# PyQt4 `QCoreApplication.arguments()` returns 'unknown' when I pass non-ASCII command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, decode

When I pass strings containing non-ASCII characters in my Python 3-PyQt4 application as command line arguments and trying to access them via `QCoreApplication.arguments()` something's going wrong:

```
In [1]: from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

In [2]: from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication

In [3]: QApplication(['a', 'b'])
Out[3]: <PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication at 0x7f987ed07510>

In [4]: QCoreApplication.arguments()
Out[4]: ['a', 'b']

In [5]: QApplication(['a', 'b', 'γ', 'δ', 'v'])
Out[5]: <PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication at 0x7f987ed07808>

In [6]: QCoreApplication.arguments()
Out[6]: ['a', 'b', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'v']

In [7]:
```

How can I fix it?

Edit: I'm using Linux.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Have you tried manually encoding the character, i.e. 'δ'.encode('utf-8')

Comment: No, because I actually pass sys.argv το QApplication. But I tried that and it works fine. So I can do something like QApplication([i.encode('utf-8') for i in sys.argv]). Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding for QApplication is Latin-1, and you need it to be UTF-8.

To get around this, you may manually encode the arguments using `.encode('utf-8')`, before passing them to `QApplication`.

Comment: It may be possible to set the encoding to UTF-8, does anyone else know how to do this?